# cannot install C++ on Netbeans 18 on Ubuntu 22.04. needs unpack200

Tags: c++, ubuntu-22.04

The C++ plugin starts installing then gets hung up needing something called unpack200. I cannot find that. How do I get past this?

tried going to /usr/lib/jvm and search the tree for unpack200*; I don't know where else to look

Comment: Some additional background information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pack200

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.